# Minecraft Spigot having problem with ImmutableList

Tags: java

in end of code is this error what problem? tried many fixes but no ones help
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwosT.png

Comment: What is the error message? Should the method return something else than a `List<String>`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ```
> return (List<String>) ImmutableList.of();
> ```

The problem with this is that the type of `ImmutableList.of()` is determined before the cast is applied.

The type of `ImmutableList.of()` in that context is `ImmutableList<Object>`. An `ImmutableList<Object>` isn't an `ImmutableList<String>`.

I'm surprised you need any type hinting here:

```
return ImmutableList.of();
```